# Improve or replacement for rsync

Tags: linux, rhel, rsync

I have a network with 80 RHEL 6.5 server.  i have a file server in this network and run rsync deamon on it. clients checks file server every 15 minute for updates and if file server files updated or added new file they download it. my problem with rsync raised when my updated files count over 800 file or size of then over 200MB, in this case full syncing client(80 server) take 6, 7 hours, so how can fix this problem?

Comment: There are plenty of options in rsync, have you explored any of them, e.g. `--ignore-existing`? Nevertheless, 6 hours for 200MB is quite extreme, do you have a network issue?

Comment: You may have already checked this, but are you sure your clients are not rolling a bigger and bigger snowball.  If the update runs every 15 minutes, will future updates be skipped while the current one continues?  If not you may have many times more than 80 rsync clients attached.  200MiBx80 = 15.6 GiB.  15.6GiB in 6 hours is 0.74 MiB per second.  That seems slow for a modern network.  I've definately had rsync achieve better results than that.

Comment: I only have desktop & use rsync. but some with servers suggest rdiff. https://rdiff-backup.net/ Sample rdiff file by TheFu
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2447368 Summary report from rdiff & use variables, example
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2422831